# Value is not passing

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, web, flutter-animation

[image]

[image]

Why the updated value of isScrolled not passing. the value is changing because when tried to print it int the setState it changes . also the SlideTransitionDemo widget is working right when I pass to it true directely

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback` inside the listener.

```
@override
  initState() {
   super.iniState();
  sc.addListener((){
   WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       setState((){
        isScrolled = (sc.offset >= 460)
       });
    });
  })}
```